# Writing a for loop for to fill in values using readline

Tags: r, readline

I have a data.frame with one column containing some value that are labeled as "Blank".

```
amount <- c(10,12,14)
description <- c("bankafschrift", "ABN", "albert heijn")
post <- ("Blank", "Bank", "Blank")

df <- data.frame(description, amount, post)
```

I would now like to write that loops over all values that are labeled "Blank" and manually provide it with input.

So therefore I wrote the following:

```
 for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {

 if (df$post == "Blank") {

    des <- df$description[i]
    var <- paste0("What is the post of: ", des)
    df$post[i] <- readline(var) 

  }
 }
```

It works for the first row but then I get the following error:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In if (df$post == "Blank") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (df$post == "Blank") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (df$post == "Blank") { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Could anybody elaborate on what going wrong and what exactly the error means?

Comment: try replacing `df$post` by `df$post[i]`

Comment: also, I would advise you to use ``df <- data.frame(description, amount, post,stringsAsFactors=F)`` otherwise your post will be factors (but you might want that)

Comment: @etienne thanks man, this totally worked